# Bris on Erev Tisha B'Av?

Tags: sources-mekorot, brit-milah, tisha-bav, meat

I seem to recall reading/seeing that one cannot serve meat at a bris on the 8th of Av (assume not on Shabbos) but I can't find it now.

Does anyone know a source that says this?

Answer (score 2):

[Rema Orach Chaim 551:10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.551.10?lang=bi) is pretty definitive that you can serve meat even on 8th of Av (if it isn't your final meal before the fast), but if it is during the week in which the fast falls the meat should be served to only a small number of guests:

> ובסעודת מצוה כגון מילה ופדיון הבן וסיום מסכת וסעודת אירוסין אוכלין בשר ושותין יין כל השייכין לסעודה אבל יש לצמצם שלא להוסיף ובשבוע שחל ט' באב בתוכה אין לאכול בשר ולשתות יין רק מנין מצומצם וזה אפי' בערב ת"ב שרי ובלבד שלא יהיה בסעודה שמפסיק בה

[Mishnah Berurah 551:77](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.551.77?lang=bi) contends that meat may be eaten by the celebrants, their very close family members, and an additional quorum of ten people.

Comment: Please check my edits match your intent

Comment: @DoubleAA When you’re thinking of 8th Av which is not during shavua shechal bo, is that Friday 8th Av or Shabbat 8th Av?

Comment: @JoelK i would think no _chiddush_ in eating meat on _shabbos_

Comment: @JoelK I guess both?